# How Unsend.it works?

Tags: email, smtp

I was a little bit surprised to see [Unsend.it](http://unsend.it/) this morning.
How is it possible to unsend or edit a sent email ?

I would like to know technical details of how this works.
Is it possible for us to achieve this through programming ? If possible can anyone present me some code sample ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't actually "un-send" the email. How it works is that the text content of the email is transposed into an image file and the text is removed from the email and replaced with the dynamic image file that contains the transposed text. So it looks like a text email, but is actually an image of the text of your email.

The image is remotely loaded from their servers so if you want to "un-send" the email, they change the image and remove the original text. The email itself remains in the recipients Inboxes', its now just a blank email that has been "un-sent".

Answer (score 0):

Update 2019:
The email is not actually sent, instead they just wait for a cancellation period (which is configurable), to actually send it. So until this time passes, the email is actually sent. So if you click cancel within the timeframe, the email is never sent.